# Check PHP coding is correct

Tags: php

can someone please check the PHP coding is correct for this
[script](http://privatepaste.com/830omeDjUJ). It needs a fresh pair of eyes to check.

Since this script is slightly older since I last worked on it, I can't remember what small change I made to fix it...

So what's wrong with it? The checkbox permissions aren't being saved at this moment - not sure why :(

```
if ($_POST) { 
$upd = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `tbl_user`  SET `username` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username'])."', `userfullname` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['fullname'])."', `useremail` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email'])."', `userlevel`= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['userlevel'])."', `usertitle` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['title'])."' WHERE `userid` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['userid'])."'");
$insert = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET
`1` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_1']) . "',    
`2` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_2']) . "',    
`3` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_3']) . "',    
`4` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_4']) . "',    
`5` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_5']) . "', 
`6` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_6']) . "',
`7` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_7']) . "',
`8` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_8']) . "',
`9` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_9']) . "',
`10` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_10']) . "',
`11` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_11']) . "',
`12` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_12']) . "',
`13` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_13']) . "',
`14` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_14']) . "',
`15` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_15']) . "',
`16` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_16']) . "',
`17` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_17']) . "',
`18` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_18']) . "',
`19` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_19']) . "',
`20` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_20']) . "',
`21` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_21']) . "',
`22` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_22']) . "'
WHERE `userid` = '$id' ")or die(mysqli_error($db));

$insert = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `tbl_usrdepts` SET
`1` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['dept_1']) . "',    
`2` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['dept_2']) . "',    
`3` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['dept_3']) . "'    
WHERE `userid` = '$id' ")or die(mysqli_error($db));
$updated = "1";} 

if(!empty($_GET['userid'])) {       
 $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from tbl_user WHERE userid = $id LIMIT 1");    
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 0) {        
   $noid = "1";    
 } else {        
   $current = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);        
   $currentperms  = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from tbl_perms WHERE userid = $id"));
   $currentdepts  = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from tbl_usrdepts WHERE userid = $id"));                        
  }} else {    
    $noidentered = "1";}
// Set Permissions
 $permissionid_select = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_perms` WHERE `userid` = '$id'")or die(mysqli_error($db));
 $permissionid = mysqli_fetch_array($permissionid_select);
 $deptid_select = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_usrdepts` WHERE `userid` = '$id'")or die(mysqli_error($db));
 $deptid = mysqli_fetch_array($deptid_select);
 $get_perms = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `perm_sets` WHERE `status` = '1' ORDER BY `id` ASC")or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

And now for the display code:

```
<tr valign="top">
<td class="alt2">Application Permissions</td>
<td class="alt2"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr valign="top"><td>
<div id="ctrl_user[membergroupids]" class="smallfont">
<?
   while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($get_perms)){

$pname = $i[pname];
$id = $i[id];
?>
    <div>
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="1" name="permsA_<? echo $id;?>" value="1" <? if($permissionid[$id] == '1') {echo ' checked="checked" ';}?> /><?echo htmlspecialchars($pname);?></div>
<? } ?>     
</tr>
</table>
<br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td class="alt1">User Departments</td>
<td class="alt1"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr valign="top"><td><div id="ctrl_user[membergroupids]" class="smallfont">
<?
$get_depts = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_depts` ORDER BY `id` ASC")or die(mysqli_error($db));
while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($get_depts)){

$dname = $i[name];
$id = $i[id];
?>      
    <div><input type="checkbox" tabindex="1" name="dept_<? echo $id ;?>" value="1" <? if($deptid[$id] == '1') {echo ' checked="checked" ';}?> /><?echo htmlspecialchars($dname);?></div>
<? } ?> 
 </tr>
</table>
<br />
</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: sweet mother of god

Comment: If you expect us to debug your code you should at least: a. include a copy of it. b. explain what do you think is wrong and what have you tried.

Comment: have you really named all your table columns as sequential numbers? Eek!

Comment: woops, ok, sorry, erm, I can try to include a copy of it in the post. Yep - the design and such isn't my worry currently, getting the thing to work is :/ Have it my way, and I'd take longer and process it all in CSS.

Comment: ok it's my own stupidity, it works :/

Answer (score 0):

A couple standard debugging techniques and comments:

- comment out presentational code. It
  just obscures things.
- `print_r($var)` immediately after
  each $var that isn't behaving. Start
  at the immediate problem and backtrack from there.
- don't use php short tags (`<?`). They
  are deprecated.
- echo out your SQL queries so you can
  see if they look the way you expect
  them to.

There is nothing immediately obvious in the giant pile of code you posted. Clean out the non-crucial stuff and you (and we) will more easily see what's going on.

Comment: Have any docs re: short tags being deprecated?  A quick google search only turned up unconfirmed rumors.

Comment: deprecated is the wrong word, but it amounts to the same thing: from the manual "There are four different pairs of opening and closing tags which can be used in PHP. Two of those, `<?php ?>` and `<script language="php"> </script>`, are always available. The other two are short tags and ASP  style tags, and can be turned on and off from the `php.ini`  configuration file. As such, while some people find short tags and ASP style tags convenient, they are less portable, and generally not recommended." http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php